# Как в Recyclerview Adapter получить id из БД? Или обработчик нажатия RecyclerView

Tags: android, база-данных, recyclerview, adapter

Попробую кратко объяснить проблему.
В **content_main.xml** поместил список `RecyclerView`
Заполняется `RecyclerView` из БД
В самой  Базе данных есть, четыре колонки: `id`, `title` -  заголовок, `value` - значение, `favor` - 1 или 0 это для добавление в избранное

Так вот есть три экрана (Активити) В первом (**MainActivity.java**) я заполняю список заголовками из БД, при нажатии на пункт списка адаптер `RecyclerAdapter` получает позицию пункта и передает во второе Активити эту позицию с помощью `Intent`

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final int idvadaptere = position;
    final String str = Integer.toString(idvadaptere);
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent ddddd = new Intent(context, LastActivity.class);
            ddddd.putExtra("position", str);
            context.startActivity(ddddd);
        }
    });
}
```

Во втором активити (**LastActivity.java**) я получаю эту позицию и с помощью ее вывожу уже данные

```
        // данные я взял пока из ресурса string.xml, 
    // заголовок
    final String[] catnames1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);
    // значение
    final String[] catnames2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names2);

    // получаем Intent извликаем из него объект
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // извлекаем из него объект
    posString = intent.getStringExtra("position");
    // преобразовать
    int posInt = Integer.parseInt(posString);

    // выводим полученные данные
    textView.setText(catnames1[posInt]);
    textView2.setText(catnames2[posInt]);
```

Пока все отлично работает. Нажал на пункт списка, открылось второе активити где выводиться заголовок и значение.

Проблема начинается с третьим активити где выводится список избранного
В третьем Активити (**FavorActivity.java**) не совпадают заголовки и значения.
Так как я в третьем активити использую тот же Адаптер, но позиция в списке уже не та.

Например: в первом Активити выводиться весь список, в третьем поле заголовок например БМВ, значение красный. Но в третьем Активити (где выводиться избранное) список уже состоит не из 300 пунктов, а например из пяти и пункт с БМВ уже находить не в третьем поля, а в первом и значения ему подставляются другие из первого поля.

Эту проблему можно было решить если получать в адаптере при клике на пункт не позицию, а именно `id`, но как это сделать??? Может кто знает, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Какая БД и если вы используете модель данных, то помещайте в нее и ID, затем в слушателе извлекайте из модели этот ID и передавайте интентом. Стоит заметить, что стартовать активити из адаптера не лучшее решение, правильнее будет прокинуть из адаптера в активити интерфейс и через него передавать данные в активити. Из активити уже запускать другую активити.

Comment: Я использую Sugar ORM, я пока не сильно разобрался как её использовать Id вроде автоматически ставиться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что у Вас хранится в mDataset? 
Вам нужно создать класс item для информации из базы

```
public class your_item_name {
private int id;
private String title;
private int value;
private int favor;

public int getFavor() {
    return favor;
}

public void setFavor(int favor) {
    this.favor = favor;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

Потом перед созданием RecyclerView делаете выборку из базы и наполняете массив вашими item:

```
private ArrayList<your_item_name> getItemsArray() {
    ArrayList<your_item_name> itemsArray = new ArrayList<your_item_name>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        your_item_name item = new your_item_name();
        item.setId(i);
        item.setTitle("Title");
        item.setValue(12);
        item.setFavor(1);

        itemsArray.set(i, item);
    }

    return itemsArray;
}
```

Передаете это все в Ваш ресайклер, и там уже передаете выбранный id.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    your_item_name item = mDataset.get(position);
    String str = String.valueOf(mDataset.get(position).getId());
    holder.mTextView.setText(str);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent ddddd = new Intent(context, LastActivity.class);
            ddddd.putExtra("position", str);
            context.startActivity(ddddd);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Нужно ID передать в другую активити, а не на экран вывести.

Comment: В  mDataset, я передаю поля колонки title
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Contact contact:allContacts){
            arr.add(contact.title); // or arr.add(contact.name); if it's public
        }

содержимое arr я уже передаю в mDataset. 
Сейчас я внимательно прочту, что Вы написали попробую разобраться, огромное спасибо за ответ. Попробую понять что не так делаю.
Я сейчас отредактирую свой вопрос, полностью весь исходный код напишу.

Comment: Код не проверил, но примерно к этому я и пришел. Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Ну вроде разобрался. Может кому пригодится, внизу решение

В MainActivity.java

из БД получил все id поместил в ArrayList

```
        ArrayList<String> arrId = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Contact contact:allContacts){
        long  i = contact.getId();
        String str = Long.toString(i);
        arrId.add(str); // or arr.add(contact.name); if it's public
    }
```

Передал вместе с заголовком в адаптар

```
mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrTitle,  arrId);
```

В RecyclerAdapter

Принял id, преобразовал в массив

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    idTab = new String[mId.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i != mId.size(); i++) {
        idTab[i] = mId.get(i);
    }

    final int idvadaptere = position;
    final String str = Integer.toString(idvadaptere);
    // выводим на экран в RecyclerView
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent ddddd = new Intent(context, LastActivity.class);
            ddddd.putExtra("id", idTab[idvadaptere]);
            context.startActivity(ddddd);
        }
    });
}
```

И вроде все работает, единственна с поиском теперь та же проблема возникла, поиск все находит, но при нажатии передает позицию элемента. К примеру позиция элемента была второй, но когда вводить в поиске заголовок, она уже становиться первой и соответсвенно при нажатии значения подставляются с первой позиции.

Сам поиск в RecyclerAdapter

```
    @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public void filter(String charText) {
    titleTab = new String[mDataset.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i != mDataset.size(); i++) {
        titleTab[i] = mDataset.get(i);
    }

    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    mDataset = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        mDataset.addAll(mCleanCopyDataset);
    } else {
        for (String item : mCleanCopyDataset) {
            if (item.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                mDataset.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

в MainActivity

```
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            mAdapter.filter(text);
            return false;
        }
    });
```